# Version control implementation advices (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control

In my company, we are going to reimplement version control for our code base.(Now we have small groups of developers, all with their own VSS version control per project).
We choose Subversion as our version control platform.

Where can i find some Best practices for implementing version control in company(how to organize repositories, what to do and when (i don't want to forget something), processes, etc.) 
I don't want to reinvent wheel.

Thanks

Comment: This should probably be community wiki

Comment: rename to "Subversion implementation advice" or similar -- "Version control implementation best practices" is awfully vague.

Comment: good comment i changed title :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading [Source/Version Control Best Practices](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.645570.5) or [Best Practices With Version Control](http://www.gamepoetry.com/blog/2009/05/15/best-practices-with-version-control/)

Answer (score 7):

You could do worse than start with the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) - it's very readable, free, well organized and has a few sections on "best practices".

Answer (score 2):

The only advice I'll offer from doing this several times is that, despite all the planning you'll do, you'll still get some stuff wrong.  Don't let the near certainty of that delay your implementation, but also don't let it prevent you from doing some planning.

In situations like yours, I've almost always had better luck by starting doing a small pilot project that we were willing to throw away, then implementing using lessons-learned.

The good news is that you already have a good bit of information in-house on how disparate groups have used version control.  That doesn't mean that it's all best-practices, but at least you have an understanding of what/how it's been used and can work from there.